# How to incrementally increase datetime values of json objects wrapped in a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe as

```
  index  json_col 
   1      json_1
   2      json_2
   ...
```

where each json_1, jason_2, etc are json files. For example, json_1 is

```
[
    {
        "origin": "a",
        "destination": "b",
        "leg": "a->b",
        "flights": [
            {
                "aircraftType": "763",
                "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 18:10:00",
                "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 22:30:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "origin": "b",
        "destination": "c",
        "leg": "b->c",
        "flights": [
            {
                "aircraftType": "73H",
                "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 14:51:00",
                "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 18:07:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "origin": "c",
        "destination": "d",
        "leg": "c-d",
        "flights": [
            {
                "aircraftType": "763",
                "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 01:30:00",
                "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 05:24:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to apply this logic for each json file in my json_col.

1. If arrivalTimeZulu of first leg > departureTimeZulu of second leg, then I want to increment second leg arrival and departure time by a certain number of days (say x days) until first leg arrivalTimeZulu < second leg departureTimeZulu.
2. If arrivalTimeZulu of second leg > departureTimeZulu of third leg, then I want to increment arrival and departure time of third leg by a certain number of days (say x days) until arrivalTimeZulu of second leg < departureTimeZulu of third leg. It is possible that arrivalTimeZulu of second leg is updated in the pervious step.

So:

- "arrivalTimeZulu":"2022-10-08 22:30:00" > "departureTimeZulu":"2022-10-08  14:51:00", thus, we add one day to departureTimeZulu/arrivalTimeZulu of second leg.
- "arrivalTimeZulu":"2022-10-09 18:07:00" > "departureTimeZulu":"2022-10-08  14:51:00", thus, we add two days to departureTimeZulu/arrivalTimeZulu of third leg.

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "origin": "a",
        "destination": "b",
        "leg": "a->b",
        "flights": [
            {
                "aircraftType": "763",
                "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 18:10:00",
                "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 22:30:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "origin": "b",
        "destination": "c",
        "leg": "b->c",
        "flights": [
            {
                "aircraftType": "73H",
                "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-09 14:51:00",
                "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-09 18:07:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "origin": "c",
        "destination": "d",
        "leg": "c-d",
        "flights": [
            {
                "aircraftType": "763",
                "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-10 01:30:00",
                "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-10 05:24:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe (your json object plus another one for the purpose of demonstration):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "index": [1, 2],
        "json_col": [
            [
                {
                    "origin": "a",
                    "destination": "b",
                    "leg": "a->b",
                    "flights": [
                        {
                            "aircraftType": "763",
                            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 18:10:00",
                            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 22:30:00",
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "origin": "b",
                    "destination": "c",
                    "leg": "b->c",
                    "flights": [
                        {
                            "aircraftType": "73H",
                            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 14:51:00",
                            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 18:07:00",
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "origin": "c",
                    "destination": "d",
                    "leg": "c-d",
                    "flights": [
                        {
                            "aircraftType": "763",
                            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 01:30:00",
                            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 05:24:00",
                        }
                    ],
                },
            ],
            [
                {
                    "origin": "a",
                    "destination": "b",
                    "leg": "a->b",
                    "flights": [
                        {
                            "aircraftType": "763",
                            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-11-09 18:10:00",
                            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-11-09 21:30:00",
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "origin": "b",
                    "destination": "c",
                    "leg": "b->c",
                    "flights": [
                        {
                            "aircraftType": "73H",
                            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-11-09 14:51:00",
                            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-11-09 19:07:00",
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "origin": "c",
                    "destination": "d",
                    "leg": "c-d",
                    "flights": [
                        {
                            "aircraftType": "763",
                            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-11-09 01:30:00",
                            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-11-09 03:24:00",
                        }
                    ],
                },
            ],
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), and [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset):

```py
for idx in df.index:
    # Make a dataframe properly formatted from each json file
    temp = pd.concat(
        [
            pd.DataFrame(df.loc[idx, "json_col"][i]["flights"])
            for i in range(len(df.loc[idx, "json_col"]))
        ],
        ignore_index=True,
    ).astype(
        {"departureTimeZulu": "datetime64[ns]", "arrivalTimeZulu": "datetime64[ns]"}
    )

    # Evaluate number of days to add to each arrival and departure dates
    temp["delta"] = (
        (temp["departureTimeZulu"] < temp["arrivalTimeZulu"].shift(1))
        .astype(int)
        .cumsum()
    )

    # Increment arrival and departure dates
    for col in ["departureTimeZulu", "arrivalTimeZulu"]:
        temp[col] = temp.apply(
            lambda x: x[col] + pd.DateOffset(days=x["delta"]), axis=1
        ).astype(str)

    # Cleanup and get data back in json file
    temp = temp.drop(columns="delta")
    new_values = temp.to_dict(orient="records")
    for i, new_value in enumerate(new_values):
        df.loc[idx, "json_col"][i]["flights"] = new_value
```

Then, you can check that each json object has be correctly modified:

```py
print(df.loc[0, "json_col"])
# Output
[
    {
        "origin": "a",
        "destination": "b",
        "leg": "a->b",
        "flights": {
            "aircraftType": "763",
            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 18:10:00",
            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-08 22:30:00",
        },
    },
    {
        "origin": "b",
        "destination": "c",
        "leg": "b->c",
        "flights": {
            "aircraftType": "73H",
            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-09 14:51:00",
            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-09 18:07:00",
        },
    },
    {
        "origin": "c",
        "destination": "d",
        "leg": "c-d",
        "flights": {
            "aircraftType": "763",
            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-10-10 01:30:00",
            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-10-10 05:24:00",
        },
    },
]

print(df.loc[1, "json_col"])
# Output
[
    {
        "origin": "a",
        "destination": "b",
        "leg": "a->b",
        "flights": {
            "aircraftType": "763",
            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-11-09 18:10:00",
            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-11-09 21:30:00",
        },
    },
    {
        "origin": "b",
        "destination": "c",
        "leg": "b->c",
        "flights": {
            "aircraftType": "73H",
            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-11-10 14:51:00",
            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-11-10 19:07:00",
        },
    },
    {
        "origin": "c",
        "destination": "d",
        "leg": "c-d",
        "flights": {
            "aircraftType": "763",
            "departureTimeZulu": "2022-11-11 01:30:00",
            "arrivalTimeZulu": "2022-11-11 03:24:00",
        },
    },
]
```